# Accessing remote device in android

Tags: java, android, remote-access, remote-server

I want to access remote device(PC) connected in LAN or wi-fi in android device,using ip address device username and password.is there any way for doing this?
what will be the right way for starting this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please refer to this link http://www.pcworld.com/article/2033284/how-to-control-your-pc-with-your-android-phone.html it might help you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Socket` to do that, just set up a `ServerSocket` on your PC, let the android open a TCP `Socket` connection with your PC and sending data vice versa. One thing, this will only apply in the SAME wifi or network, you can't do that on 3G due to the NAT restriction.

Check out this link: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/, you can set up your `Server` part on Java, not neccesary to be Android. Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to access remote device like teamviewer